# 2 Variables, 6 replicates, Dependent Var is number of days. What analysis?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, model

I'm analyzing # of days a particular bird species was observed in a forested area, let's say out of 100 days. I have a control plot, a masticated plot, and a burned and masticated plot. I have pre and post treatments. I conducted this at 6 sites that are mostly similar. What kind of test would you recommend I run? Data would look something like the table below.

| Trial | #days bird observed |
| --- | --- |
| Control Pretreatment Site1 | 86/100 days |
| Control Posttreatment Site1 | 85/100 days |
| Mastication Pretreatment Site3 | 86/100 days |
| Mastication Posttreatment Site3 | 20/100 days |
| Mast+Burn Pretreatment Site6 | 82/100 days |
| Mast+Burn Posttreatment Site6 | 10/100 days |

I was thinking this could be analyzed by a multilevel model where I would include treatment type and timepoint as fixed independent variables, forest site as a random independent variable, and number of days detected as the dependent variable.

I am also not sure if I'm structuring my dependent variable correctly. Because it's number of days a bird is observed during a time period, can I just use the number like 84 for 84 out of 100 days? Or do I have to consider it as a binomial somehow because somedays have confirmed observations (1) and some days have no confirmed observations (0).

Thank you.

Comment: So to clarify do you have 36 observations in total? If not then some more detail is going to be needed. With only 6 forest sites I would probably use that as fixed not random.

Comment: @mdewey Yes I could have 36 data inputs total by aggregating them as number of days observed for the study period. I was also maybe thinking that each day could be a datapoint as a 0 or 1 for detected or not, but I don't think that's necessary. Are you saying you would then recommend the MLM with three fixed variables then? Not another test?

Comment: @mdewey I also have data for several bird species, but I dont know how to aggregate all of them together into the same test.